# Warning about missing GTK icon in Python executable

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pyinstaller

In an executable application I write using Python and PyGTK, popping up a FileChooserDialog gives me this warning:

```
GtkWarning: Could not find the icon 'gtk-file'.
The 'hicolor' theme was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
You can get a copy from:
        http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases
```

And the link takes me to an archive that appears to be written for Linux. This warning doesn't inhibit the operation of my program, but it is annoying and I think it is confusing my users. It doesn't happen when I run the application from source, only when I build it into an executable with pyinstaller first. Does anyone know how I can locate this icon?

Comment: If you are on Linux type "find /usr/share/icons -name gtk-file.png" without double quotes.  That should tell you where the icon file is.  Oh yeah, like pythonm said, what platform are you running this on?  Are you running from sources AND building the executable and running the executable on the same platform?

Comment: Can you show the spec file used by pyinstaller please?

Comment: I believe the binary is only being used on Windows. The spec file is here: http://pastebin.com/TXmxsaNy

Answer (score 1):

I solved but... illogically.. I think.
Theoretically, **`pygtk`** should have the full icon set embedded by default, so the real oddity is "why it logs those warning?".
The solution (worked for my four projects):

1. In the root of your project, there should exists a **`share`** folder ( if not, create it ), you have to make these additional subfolders:

   `YourProjectRoot / share / icons /`**`hicolor /`**
2. Download the [official binary icon theme for gnome](ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gnome-icon-theme/2.24/gnome-icon-theme_2.24.0-1_win32.zip) ( a 12 MB ZIP-file )
3. Unzip the archive, in `gnome-icon-theme_2.24.0-1_win32.zip/share/icons/gnome/` find the file **`index.theme`** and copy it to **`hicolor /`** folder you created.

That's all